# Regular expression testing the new password

Tags: javascript, regex

Hello I am working on a javascript that is suppose to test the password field. However I can't seem to get it to work. Nothing bad happens the page loads but seems like the script isn't working. Here is what I have written up so far. I want it to check for a Upper and lower case letter, a number and a non-regular expression. Lenght isn't important just that it has one of each. Here is what I have written so far.

**UPDDATE: Found a simplier way of writing the script. And I can get it to give me a alert whenever the password field is wrong. But I can't get the true statements to work to where it will do the document button click.**

```
var str= passwordFieldForm;
    var patt=/[a-z]/g;
    var patt2 = /[A-Z]/g; 
    var patt3 = /[0-9]/g; 
    var patt4 = /[~\!@#\$%\^&*_\-\+=`\|\\(\)\{\}\[\]:;"'<>,\.\?\/]/g; 

    var result=patt.test(str);
    var result2=patt2.test(str);
    var result3=patt3.test(str);
    var result4=patt4.test(str);

    if (!result)
      alert("Needs a lowercase letter");

    if (!result2)
      alert("Needs a Uppercase Letter")

    if (!result3)
      alert("Needs a Number.")

    if (!result4)
      alert("Needs a special character")


    if (result) && (result2) && (result3) && (result4) == true
      document.getElementById("kioskform:broswerPasswordSubmit").click();
```

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle for this? A cursory glance suggests you have too many/too few braces though.

Comment: `if result = 'true'` needs to be `if result == 'true'` for starters

Comment: `result == true` is probably better still, since according to the chrome interpreter, `true != 'true'`

Comment: `if result = 'true'` should actually be `if (result == true)`, or simply `if(result)`

Comment: Tip: open up the developer console on your browser, you'll see the syntax errors right away.

Comment: There's a few quite elementary flaws with the code as it stands. This question might be a good starting point - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2970314/a-beginners-guide-to-learning-javascript

Comment: Don't know what a jsfiddle is, could you explain?

Comment: Updated the code now just need to get the true statement working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be a bit closer to what you want, I've not tested it, but it should be more in the right direction:

```
function test(password)
{
    var patt1 = /[a-z]/g;
    var patt2 = /[A-Z]/g;
    var patt3 = /[0-9]/g;
    var patt4 = /[~\!@#\$%\^&*_\-\+=`\|\\(\)\{\}\[\]:;"'<>,\.\?\/]/g;

    if (!patt1.test(password)) {
        return ("You need a lowercase letter.");
    }

    if (!patt2.test(password)) {
        return ("You need an uppercaseletter.");
    }

    if (!patt3.test(password)) {
        return ("You need a number.");
    }

    if (!patt4.test(password)) {
        return ("You need to use a one of the following characters '~!@#$%^&*_-+=`|\(){}[;.");
    }
}
```

Comment: `password` isn't a parameter. Also: why do you need to call the function multiple times?

Comment: I've no idea, he returns in each of his 'if' statements in the OP question, why don't you ask him?  I was just trying to make it less evil :-)

Comment: In that case +1 for making it less evil! ;-)

Comment: don't know about the evil part lol, I am just wondering why your calling it a function, I must still be thinking of python not js, didn't know it works both ways. But the code doesn't seem to work on the broswer. I added a static variable that should work but it didn't seem to work.

Comment: @Adrian Thompson Phillips  Well thank you the script you provided helped me make a much less eviler code lol. It looks nicer i think thank you for your help.

Comment: lol, Just need to get my true statement to work.

Answer (score 1):

This line is at fault:

```
return ("you need to use a one of the following characters '~!@#$%^&*_-+=`|\(){}[]:;"'<>,.?/'.")
```

You need to escape the quote and the slash in it.

```
return ("you need to use a one of the following characters '~!@#$%^&*_-+=`|\\(){}[]:;\"'<>,.?/'.")
```

Also you use `==` instead of `=` for comparisons, `true` instead of `"true"`. And be in the habbit of always using { } for the contents of your if statements instead of relying on tabbing.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out to me, really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape several of those characters in your last regex test:

```
 var patt4 = /[~!@#$%\^&\*_-\+=`\|\(\)\{\}\[\]\:;"'<>,\.\?\/]/g;
```

If in doubt, escape the character with a backslash `\`. Nothing will happen if you escape a character that doesn't need escaping.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out to me. Really appreciate it.