# how to declare array of object in javascript?

Tags: java, javascript

I am new to javascript i have a java classses -

1st class-

```
public class Page {

    private String url;
    private long timeout;
    private PVforPage[] pvs;     <-- specifically how I can declare this in javascript
}
```

2nd class-

```
public class PVforPage {

    private String url;
    private Layout layout;
    private Map<String, String> headers;
    private long ttl;
}
```

please any one create a corresponding javascript object for above classess

Comment: [Look here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_array.asp).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2970314/a-beginners-guide-to-learning-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is the closest for your case:

```
var page = {
    url: "",
    timeout: 0,
    pvs: [
        {
            url: "",
            layout: "",
            headers: ["", ""],
            ttl: 0
        }
    ]
}
```

Seeing that Javascript isn't so *typed* as Java, I've used some generic types for your Java types `Layout` and `Map` that I don't really know what is.

**UPDATE:**

See [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w63jw/). Is just a example of how work with js objects, instance, properties and methods. It's to study and learn. Hope you like.

Comment: their is any way to declare object pvs different and then call it's array instance in page object declartion...
like -
var pv={
            url: "",
            layout: "",
            headers: ["", ""],
            ttl: 0
        };
var page ={
      url:"",
      timeout:0,
      pvs = Array of pv() some thing 
}

Comment: @level_0 I've updated my question with some examples in a fiddle. You know how to use the browser's console?

Comment: thanq for ur link it helps me lot .... :)

Comment: @level_0 nice! If this answers your questions, please mark as accepted.

Comment: [@DontvotemeDown](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1267304/dontvotemedown) your jsfidle link is not my ans but your link is useful for me lot.It is starting kick for me. The sol that i want is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5Jyuy/)