# How do i make html code go into colour?

Tags: javascript, html

If you put this into sublime it doesnt work. can anyone help me? its meant to be traffic lights that stay stationary. please can someone help? im not allowed to use adbanner but dont know how to make it work

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
function changeImage()
{
    var img = document.getElementById("img");
    img.src = images[x];
    x++;

    if(x >= images.length){
            x = 0;
        } 

        fadeImg(img, 100, true);
        setTimeout("changeImage()", 30000);
    }

    function fadeImg(el, val, fade){
        if(fade === true){
            val--;
        }else{
            val ++;
        }

        if(val > 0 && val < 100){
            el.style.opacity = val / 100;
            setTimeout(function(){fadeImg(el, val, fade);}, 10);
        }
    }

    var images = [],
    x = 0;

    images[0] = "image1.jpg";
    images[1] = "image2.jpg";
    images[2] = "image3.jpg";
    setTimeout("changeImage()", 30000);

<img id="img" src="startpicture.jpg">
```

Comment: first of all this is JavaScript not php and second u dont use <script></script> to execute it. then ur first function dont Closes and the other function is within a function

Comment: At a first glance I spot missing `<script>` tags and parenthesis.

Comment: @KikiTheOne where did i use script tags , im confused

Comment: You didn't THATS THE PROBLEM

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2970314/a-beginners-guide-to-learning-javascript

Comment: @RiggsFolly nahh sick name, he said u dont use script tags

Comment: @alexbwithtek Now that you know that you completely forgot to use `<script>` tags, your next step is simply Googling how to use `<script>` tags and how JavaScript even works.

Comment: @alexbwithtek No he said ___you didn't use and <script> tags___ But you should, you cannot run javascript on a page unless you tell the page it is javascript by using `<script></script>` tags around the javascript code. Otherwise the browser things its just BAD HTML

Answer (score 0):

You can do below changes to your script for successful execution of the script:

```js
// below script will be in script tag

var images = [],
x = 0;
$(document).ready(function() { // put below script in document.ready()
    images[0] = "image1.jpg";
    images[1] = "image2.jpg";
    images[2] = "image3.jpg";
    setTimeout("changeImage()", 30000);
});
function changeImage()
{
var img = document.getElementById("img");
img.src = images[x];
x++;

if(x >= images.length){
        x = 0;
    } 

    fadeImg(img, 100, true);
    setTimeout("changeImage()", 500);
}

function fadeImg(el, val, fade){
    if(fade === true){
        val--;
    }else{
        val ++;
    }

    if(val > 0 && val < 100){
        el.style.opacity = val / 100;
        setTimeout(function(){fadeImg(el, val, fade);}, 10);
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="img" src="startpicture.jpg">
```

Comment: Why should the OP _Do below changes_ A **good answer** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way,
not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO that may find this question and be reading your answer.

Comment: Also JQuery has its own [`fadeIn`](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/) But the OP was not using jQuery anyway