# How can I make the width of an element a percentage of its parent while the using position: fixed property?

Tags: html, css

Here I have the following structure: `parent` > `container` > `main-section` > `post_creation` > `h3` and an `input` field.

I need the `h3` element to be fixed on the screen so that when I scroll up and down the h3 element remains visible. At the same time, I need the `h3` element's width to be 98% of `post_creation`. However, what is happening is that the width is set to be 98% of the page width.

```css
.parent {
  height: 200vh;
  width: 400px;
}

h3 {
  position: fixed;
  width: 98%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="left-section"></div>
      <div class="main-section">
        <div class="post_creation">
          <h3>home</h3>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Aliens thinking of what?">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="right-section"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: `fixed` is **always** related to the viewport. If you show us your use case we might be able to help rather than just vaguely describing the problem. Why is `fixed` a requirement? Would `sticky` be an option?

Comment: I did make an edit ..
see if that is not enough tell me please ..

Comment: We're still missing some of your CSS but I tried to improve your question. Can you provide the rest of your relevant CSS? You referred specifically to the `post_creation` class but didn't provide the CSS for it.

Answer (score 0):

When an element has a `fixed` position, it is taken out of the normal html flow, so the element doesn't know anything about its surrounding elements. Hence you can only set the width of it as a percentage of the surrounding `window`.

You could use javascript to get what you want. Simply take 98% of the `width` of the element with class `post_creation` (which is `400px` in this case), and set the `h3` to that width (in this case `392px`).

```js
var postCreationEl = document.querySelector('.post_creation');
var h3Element = document.querySelector('h3');
var style = window.getComputedStyle(postCreationEl, null);
var width = style.width;
width = parseInt(width.replace("px", ""));
var widthForH3 = Math.floor(width * (98 / 100));
h3Element.style.width = widthForH3.toString() + "px";
```

```css
.parent {
  height: 200vh;
  width: 400px;
  background-color:blue;
}

h3 {
  position: fixed;
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="left-section"></div>
        <div class="main-section">
            <div class="post_creation">
                <h3>home</h3>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Aliens thinking of what?">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="right-section"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I haven't started learning Javascript yet .. so, could you please tell me what I need to learn so that I can understand the code you've written ..,??

Comment: Check this question’s answers for links to beginner guides: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2970314/a-beginners-guide-to-learning-javascript

Comment: the first two lines is for adding the two selectors inside suitable named variables .. the third line is for getting all the properties of postCreation and saving it in another variable called style .. the fourth is to chose the width property of all the other properties stored in the variable style then save it in variable width .. the fifth is to convert width to be integer and remove "px" so it just saves '400' .. the sixth line is saving 98% of the width in widthForH3 .. finally set the width of the style of h3element to be = the previous calculation and adding back the "px" .. am I right?

Comment: Yes. You are right.